# Can't access stored ClaimsPrincipal in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, claims-based-identity

I've implemented a claim-based authorization on ASP.NET Core 3.1, where I've stored authentication info through claims and I need to retrieve it after signing in.

I found a post on StackOverFlow and did what it said exactly; Now, I've faced another problem.

**Problem**

I try to get the `ClaimsPrincipal` which I stored it while signing in. but once I try to retrieve it, it returns null; I read somewhere the `ClaimsPrincipal` was not stored on the same thread. Then, how do I fix it?

Configuring the authentication and authorization in `Startup.cs` like this:

```
services.AddAuthentication("Authn").AddCookie("Authn", options => {
                options.Cookie.Name = "Authn";
                options.LoginPath = "/Views/Account/SignIn";
            });
services.AddAuthorization(options => {
                options.AddPolicy("userSignInPolicy", p => p.RequireClaim("Role", "User"));
            });
```

This is where authentication is done and `ClaimsPrincipal` gets stored:

```
List<Claim> uclaims = new List<Claim>() {
                        new Claim("Role","User"),
                        new Claim("ID",p.User_id.ToString())
                        };

ClaimsIdentity userid = new ClaimsIdentity(uclaims, "Authn");
ClaimsPrincipal usercp = new ClaimsPrincipal(userid);

await HttpContext.SignInAsync("Authn", usercp);

Thread.CurrentPrincipal = usercp; //This is where ClaimsPrincipal is stored
return RedirectToAction("userDashboard");
```

And this is when I try to retrieve it:

```
public IActionResult userDashboard()
{
    var id = (ClaimsIdentity)Thread.CurrentPrincipal; //id is returned null here :(
    //rest of the action
}
```

Didn't find any similar issue on StackOverflow. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to store `ClaimsPrincipal` in `Thread.CurrentPrincipal`.

Inside your Controllers simply use `this.User` to access the `ClaimsPrincipal`.

Comment: You wouldn't believe how much this eased my task! I searched an entire hour and yet found no straight solution. Perhaps because the article I used to implement the code above, was posted in 2014!!!

Comment: At the speed technology is changing that article is probably extremely outdated :)